# Change parameter without changing the subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

My Angular component can use a query parameter `status` to filter the displayed results. It will go into the store using a selector and that Observable `this.items$` is then kept in the component.

This is the code I have currently written:

```js
this.route.queryParams.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe((params: Params) => {
      const status = params['status'];
      if (status) {
        this.items$ = this.store.select(selectItemsByStatus, {status: status});
      }
      else {
        this.items$ = this.store.select(selectItemsByStatus, {status: 'all'});
      }
    });
```

Even though this works, my feeling says that this can be done differently, more logically, more reactive if you will. I don't think I need to do the select over and over again. Is there a way to keep ONE select that will emit different values when the status changes?

Comment: what is the difference in the data being returned? If you make one select the subscription will be updated during the life of the site. Why don't you (instead) modify the selector (in your reducer/index) that handles this filter. The Action is already returning the data to state presumably. Or create a new select at your reducer to handle the return of the filtered data.

Comment: The selector has a props object and does the filtering based on the status property. I want to change the prop so the selector emits the items that match the filter.

Answer (score 1):

> My feeling says that this can be done differently, more logically, more reactive if you will

You are absolutely right on this - When building an observable you usually need to think in the opposite direction: Instead of "this thing has changed, I need to set this value" is "This value, what does it depend on?"

In your case, it seems like `items$` depends only on the route's `queryParams`, so we can build a stream like this:

```js
items$ = this.route.queryParams.pipe(
  switchMap(params => {
    const status = params['status'];
    if (status) {
      return this.store.select(selectItemsByStatus, {status: status});
    }
    else {
      return this.store.select(selectItemsByStatus, {status: 'all'});
    }
  })
);
```

This also has the advantage that you don't need to deal with another subscription - So I think the `takeUntil` would be redundant here, it's up to the consumer of this stream to unsubscribe when needed.

If items$ depends on more things, you can combine other observables with combineLatest, merge, concat, etc.

Edit: Note that this will call `this.store.select` every time `queryParams` emits something, even if the status doesn't change. But there's an easy fix for this:

```js
items$ = this.route.queryParams.pipe(
  map(params => params['status']),
  // Only emit if the value (status) changes
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(status => {
    if (status) {
      return this.store.select(selectItemsByStatus, {status: status});
    }
    else {
      return this.store.select(selectItemsByStatus, {status: 'all'});
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is my actual goal to setup the store subscription so that I only subscribe once, and the emitted values would change when the filter changes. I like your idea of reversing the thought process when working with obervables here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combineLatest()` with two parameters:

```
statusFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject('');

items$ = combineLatest(
  this.store.select(selectItems),
  statusFilter$,
).pipe(
  map(([items, statusFilter]) => items.filter(item => item.status === statusFilter)), // ... or whatever
);
```

Then changing the status filter is with `statusFilter$.next('status')`. Maybe in your case you could just subscribe the query parameter directly into the filter (but this will also propagate complete notifications so maybe this is not exactly what you want):

```
this.route.queryParams.pipe(...).subscribe(statusFilter$);
```

Comment: The filter is passed to the selector as props. So it's the selector that does the filtering, not my component. Is there a way to combine that?

Comment: You want to change the props object that is already passed into `this.store.select()`?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's that is comes down to. Is that even possible?

Comment: You want to modify the same object instance and there's not way this is going to trigger anything inside store selector.

Comment: This would probably only work if my selector uses a filter that is also in the store, and the `selectItems` selector uses that as child selector. I read that in NgRx 12 props for selectors are deprecated anyway, so it might be better to find a solution that does not use props.

Comment: If you add another state param then it will definitely work but you'll have only one possible state for `items`. You won't be able to use for example two different components with different filters.

Comment: That is a very good point. Maybe I am overcomplicating things. I should keep it simple, subscribe to the all the items and filter as in your suggestion. That still is one subscription to the store, right?

Comment: exactly, there will be just one subscription that emits only when the stored value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered `@ngrx/router-store`? It might be overkill for what you need, but if you are accessing the router state a lot it could be worth your while.

You could defer most of the logic to a selector like so:

```js
export const selectVisibleItems = createSelector(
    selectState,
    selectQueryParams, // this is provided by @ngrx/router-store
    (state, params) => 
         // Do your selecting of data here depending on the query params - just making something up here for an example
         state?.items?.filter(
             item => item?.status === (params?.['status'] ?? 'all')
)
```

Then in your component, you don't even have to bother with passing props to your selectors, which as you correctly state are deprecated.

```js
items$ = this.store.select(selectVisibleItems);
```

I always try to put as much logic into the selectors as possible. From the `ngrx` site:

> When using the createSelector and createFeatureSelector functions @ngrx/store keeps track of the latest arguments in which your selector function was invoked. Because selectors are pure functions, the last result can be returned when the arguments match without reinvoking your selector function. This can provide performance benefits, particularly with selectors that perform expensive computation. This practice is known as memoization.

For this reason, I generally avoid using operators like `combineLatest` when I can compose the same result using selectors.